# Azure Automation runbook fails when triggered from a Webhook

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-automation

Azure Automation runbook fails when triggered from a Webhook
We have a runbook that runs just fine when launched via the “Start” button in the Azure Portal.

The exact same runbook fails when launched from a webhook using the exact same parameters.

The issue is that after the code in the runbook opens a valid connection to Azure, it tries to get one of the databases we are going to work with and it fails with an exception that reads “Resource group '''' could not be found.”

The same exact code and parameters work without any issues when run outside the Webhook.

We added code to get the context after the code does the login and we checked that the context name, subscription ID and Tenant ID are valid, and we even pass the context to the Get-AzSqlDatabase call and still it fails when triggered via the webhook. We are not sure what else we can try to diagnose and correct the issue.

Here is a sample of the code we run and where it fails...

```
. . .
Function Login {
    Disable-AzContextAutosave -Scope Process

    Write-Output "Logging in to Azure..."
    $connectionName = "GoodTestingConnection"    
    try{
            Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Tenant $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
            -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
            -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint
        }
        catch {
            Write-Output "Error loging in to Azure: $_"
            throw "Error loging in to Azure: $_"
        }        
}

$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

if ($WebHookData) {
    Write-Output "Running runbook from web hook request"
    $wbRunParams = (ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $WebHookData.RequestBody)
    Write-Output "Webhook parameters $wbRunParams"
    $client = $wbRunParams.client

    Write-Output "Running process for client $client"        
}

Login

$ctx = Get-AzContext
Write-Output "Context nanme: $($ctx.Name)"
Write-Output "Environment name: $($ctx.Environment.Name)"
Write-Output "Subscription ID: $($ctx.Subscription.Id)"
Write-Output "Tenant ID: $($ctx.Tenant.Id)"

Write-Output "Getting the 'from' Db..."
$fromDb = Get-AzSqlDatabase `
                -DatabaseName $copyFromDbName `
                -ServerName $copyFromServer `
                -ResourceGroupName $copyFromRG `
                -DefaultProfile $ctx
    $fromDb

#The code never reaches this point as it fails on the previous call
. . .
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Here is what worked for me.

When the automation runbook is triggered via the start option or via the test pane, the, the format needs to be converted. This is when you would use

```
$wbRunParams = (ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $WebHookData.RequestBody)
```

When the runbook has to be triggered directly by webhook, no need to convert and the below would work.

```
$wbRunParams = $WebHookData.RequestBody
```